# Boostrap Cards Loop Razor

Tags: razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create an HTML structure using Bootstrap where I would have 4 cards per row but Without Defining the Row div more of just a container and include X cards within it and just have it automatically line-break after 4 cards on desktop screens.

Reason being I'm going to use Razor to create a loop and pull my card contents from a table but I don't see how I can loop the following:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">(MY CARD HTML)</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">(MY CARD HTML)</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">(MY CARD HTML)</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">(MY CARD HTML)</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">(MY CARD HTML)</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">(MY CARD HTML)</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">(MY CARD HTML)</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">(MY CARD HTML)</div>
</div>
```

As opposed to this that I could just loop my `CARD HTML` in razor without defining rows.

```
<div class="card-deck">
(MY CARD HTML)
(MY CARD HTML)
(MY CARD HTML)
(MY CARD HTML)
<!--LINE/ROW BREAKS HERE-->
(MY CARD HTML)
(MY CARD HTML)
(MY CARD HTML)
(MY CARD HTML)
</div>
```

My Razor script would look something like:

```
<div class="card-deck">
@foreach (var row in CK.Cards("ID='" + TknParams.ID + "'")) {
 <div class="card">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">@row.Title</h4>
    <p class="card-text">@row.Description</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">@row.Link</a>
  </div>
</div>
}
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To loop what you have shown above, you can use one row, since each div column is 3 it would go to a new row if 12(3x4) is reached. Something like this:

```
<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="row">
    @foreach (var row in CK.Cards("ID='" + TknParams.ID + "'")) {
     <!-- Display a div of col-sm-3 containing the card up to n number of times, ie in a loop -->
     <div class="col-sm-3">(MY CARD HTML)</div>
    }
  </div>
</div>
```

See a sample fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/akassama/6y6w2saf/)